# Linked file do not close unless the application is closed

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, userform

I have a problem that turn my head for more than three days now, the problem is that I am using a data-entry app using vba , I have linked some other excel workbooks to my database entry and when I open those linked files from the list box of my app: they open normally but they do not wanna close unless I close my app (and all the excel workbooks are closed), if any one can help me I would be gratfule. here is my vba:

```
`Private Sub cmbfichedevie_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
Set shsearch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Searchdata")
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iRowsearchdat As Long
Dim ttt As Long

With shsearch
ttt = Selected_list + 1
iRowsearchdata = [Counta(Searchdata!A:A)]
If iRowsearchdata > 1 Then
    If Selected_list >= iRowsearchdata Or Selected_list = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Aucun élément n'est sélectionné.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Ouvrir"
    Else
        If shsearch.Cells(ttt, 12) = "" Or shsearch.Cells(ttt, 12) = "No file" Then
        MsgBox "Il n'y a aucune fiche de vie pour cet article.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Ouvrir"
        Else
        'shsearch.Cells(ttt, 12).Hyperlinks(1).Follow
        Workbooks.Open .Cells(ttt, 12)
        'Unload Me
        End If
    End If
    Exit Sub
Else
With sh
ttt = Selected_list + 1
iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)]

If Selected_list >= iRow Or Selected_list = 0 Then
MsgBox "Aucun élément n'est sélectionné.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Ouvrir"
Else

    If sh.Cells(ttt, 12) = "" Or sh.Cells(ttt, 12) = "No file" Then
    MsgBox "Il n'y a aucune fiche de vie pour cet article.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Ouvrir"
    Else
    'sh.Cells(ttt, 12).Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=True
    Workbooks.Open .Cells(ttt, 12)
    'Unload Me
    End If
End If
End With
End If
End With
End Sub
```

`

Comment: Not 100% sure what's going on in your code. But would `Workbook.close` help you to close the workbooks?

Comment: if I use workbook.close the linked file will open then close directly, but I want it to open so that I look at its data then I close it without the need to close my main workbook (app(userform))